# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField List of items symmetrical

Tags: flutter, layout, dropdown

I would like to show `DropdownButtonFormField`'s List of item in the middle of screen. It's never aligned to the center. `DropdownButtonFormField` is centered already. Spacing on the left and right side are different.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be try this
Add **DropdownButtonFormField()** inside **Padding()** Widget

```
Padding (
  padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
  child:DropdownButtonFormField(),
),
```

Comment: It couldn't help. It's still not symmetrically aligned.

Comment: can you post your new image

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
DropdownButton(
     isExpanded: true
     value: fieldSelected,
     items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((var value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Center(
                 child: Text(
                        "Your text",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                 );
           }).toList(),
      ),
```

Comment: I'd like to center whole list, not Text on list item.